# Importing data from a CSV-file into a dictionary, where the keys are country names and the values are np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary

I'm completely stuck on this task, which reads:

> Create a function that imports data from a csv-file into a dictionary.
> The keys should be country names and the values should be
> numpy.arrays. The function should take a filename as argument and
> return the data "dictionary".

Formatting of the csv.file:

e.g Belarus,599,599,599,601,601,601

Example output:

{’Andorra ’: [580, ..., 2650],

’Angola ’: [606, ..., 21900],

etc.}

As of right now, this code is the closest I've gotten to the correct output:

```
import numpy as np

def load_csv(filename):

    dictionary = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()
        for line in data:
            list = line.split(",")
            dictionary[list[0]] = np.array(list[1:])

    return dictionary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = average_income.csv
    print(load_csv(filename))
```

Which gives the output:

> {'Andorra': array(['603', ..., '2650\n'], dtype='<U6],
>
> 'Angola': array(['606', ..., '21900\n'], dtype='<U5],
>
> etc.}

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Jsut edited my answer

change `.strip()` to another line.

```py
def load_csv(filename):

    dictionary = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()
        for line in data:
            list = line.strip().split(",") # <--- add .strip()
            dictionary[list[0]] = np.array(list[1:])

    return dictionary


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = average_income.csv
    print(load_csv(filename))
```

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'strip'".
The values are meant to be an array, although I've used it pootly so the output is incorrect unfortunately.

Comment: Just edited answer. Try it

Comment: `list` is a keyword for python built-in function, you should use another variable name rather than use it.

Comment: If it worked, could you please check the mark beside my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: just drop `np.array`, it should be what you want